# Selecting child.id from parent table

Tags: sql

In Parse you can select or include a key from a pointer. `Select key Parent.child.id`

Is it possible to do the same in SQL if you have child indexed to parent?

```
SELECT Parent.child.id
```

Comment: Yes, you do a join from the parent to child table.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL you do this:

```
Select * from parent, child where parent.id = child.id;
```

Comment: It's better to use the modern explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the where clause

Comment: Pointed noted .